# How to insert multiple records in rails3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails3.0 how to insert multiple records in a table? plz tell me any example application.

Answer (score 5):

You can use transactions

```
titles = ["T-Shirt", "Boots", "Cap"]

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  titles.each do |title|
    Thing.create(:title => title)
  end
end
```

Ot make one sql query:

```
query = []
titles.each do |title|
  query << "('#{title}')"
end
sql = "INSERT INTO things ('title') VALUES #{query.join(", ")}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Quite interesting article

> http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/